# Does ansible transfer files securely?

Tags: encryption, ansible, file-transfer, ansible-vault

I'm using Ansible 2.2 to manage some cloud servers from my laptop. I want to transfer an OpenSSL private key to a specific location on one of the servers, to be used by nginx for TLS termination. Naturally, this is a file that should be kept secret, so I've encrypted it using [Ansible Vault](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/playbooks_vault.html). But Vault only protects a file on-disk on the Control Machine. It doesn't come into play when transferring data from the Control Machine to a Managed Node.

I want to be sure that the private key is not compromised in transit by someone monitoring network traffic. There's no specific mention of what I'm looking for that I can see in the [docs for the `copy` module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/copy_module.html). As far as I know, all of my communication with the managed nodes is done via SSH. Is that a safe assumption? Does it include file transfers?

Comment: Rene's answer is correct. For further assurance you can run your playbook with -vvvv to see all the traffic going over the ssh connection which will give you the comfort that it is being sent over a secure channel to your node e.g. `ansible-playbook -vvvv myplaybook.yml`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is it depends on the type of connection.

There's an Ansible copy plugin which defers to the connection. The source code for the plugin is here:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/bc66faa328b1413646ec249cd2753de5e09f1a35/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py

This defers copies to `ActionBase._transfer_file` which then defers to `Connection.put_file`.

There are many different implementations of connections, some of which are secure and some are not. If you're using an SSH connection then it uses either scp or sftp to do the actual copy and is secure.

This can be seen in the ssh source here:

https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/442af3744ebd60c7ffcaae22b61fb762ccc7c425/lib/ansible/plugins/connection/ssh.py#L954

Which delegates `put_file` to `_file_transport_command` which then can use scp, sftp, "smart", or pipes. Smart detects which of the other three is best to use.

*Note: There's an Ansible copy module which only copies files locally and has no need for secure copy. That's what my previous answer erroneously pointed to and so I deleted it.*

Answer (score 3):

You're right, all communication with the managed node is securely done via ssh. Your vault is decrypted on the controller, the plaintext private key is sent through a secure ssh connection and dropped on your target node.

The plaintext private key may become unsecure on your target node, depending on who can login, ownerships, group memberships, access permissions and so on. It's up to you to configure those securely.

Comment: I tried to find pinpoint the place in ansible code that is responsible for that transfer in the `copy` module but I couldn't do this. Do you know where I can find it?

Comment: @PiotrBabij https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/devel/lib/ansible/modules/files/copy.py seems to be it but no references to ssh or secure copy.

Comment: @PiotrBabij actually that's only for local copies, copy plugin is here https://github.com/ansible/ansible/blob/bc66faa328b1413646ec249cd2753de5e09f1a35/lib/ansible/plugins/action/copy.py see new answer for more details.